# Continuous colormap fill between two lines

Tags: python, matplotlib

It's possible to fill between lines with a color:

http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/fill_between_demo.html

It's also possible to use a continuous colormap for a line:

http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/multicolored_line.html

Is it possible (and reasonably easy) to use a continuous colormap for the colored fill between two lines?  For example, the color fill may change along x based on the difference between the two lines at x (or based on another set of data).

Answer (score 12):

I found a solution to this problem. It builds on the brilliant but hacky [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215276/how-to-fill-rainbow-color-under-a-curve-in-python-matplotlib?lq=1) of @Hooked. You create a 2D grid filed from lots of small boxes. It's not the fastest solution but it should be pretty flexible (more so than solutions which apply imshow to the patches).

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

#Plot a rectangle
def rect(ax, x, y, w, h, c,**kwargs):
    #Varying only in x
    if len(c.shape) is 1:
        rect = plt.Rectangle((x, y), w, h, color=c, ec=c,**kwargs)
        ax.add_patch(rect)
    #Varying in x and y
    else:
        #Split into a number of bins
        N = c.shape[0]
        hb = h/float(N); yl = y
        for i in range(N):
            yl += hb
            rect = plt.Rectangle((x, yl), w, hb, 
                                 color=c[i,:], ec=c[i,:],**kwargs)
            ax.add_patch(rect)

#Fill a contour between two lines
def rainbow_fill_between(ax, X, Y1, Y2, colors=None, 
                         cmap=plt.get_cmap("Reds"),**kwargs):
    plt.plot(X,Y1,lw=0)  # Plot so the axes scale correctly

    dx = X[1]-X[0]
    N  = X.size

    #Pad a float or int to same size as x
    if (type(Y2) is float or type(Y2) is int):
        Y2 = np.array([Y2]*N)

    #No colors -- specify linear
    if colors is None:
        colors = []
        for n in range(N):
            colors.append(cmap(n/float(N)))
    #Varying only in x
    elif len(colors.shape) is 1:
        colors = cmap((colors-colors.min())
                      /(colors.max()-colors.min()))
    #Varying only in x and y
    else:
        cnp = np.array(colors)
        colors = np.empty([colors.shape[0],colors.shape[1],4])
        for i in range(colors.shape[0]):
            for j in range(colors.shape[1]):
                colors[i,j,:] = cmap((cnp[i,j]-cnp[:,:].min())
                                    /(cnp[:,:].max()-cnp[:,:].min()))

    colors = np.array(colors)

    #Create the patch objects
    for (color,x,y1,y2) in zip(colors,X,Y1,Y2):
        rect(ax,x,y2,dx,y1-y2,color,**kwargs)


# Some Test data    
X = np.linspace(0,10,100)
Y1 = .25*X**2 - X
Y2 = X
g = np.exp(-.3*(X-5)**2)

#Plot fill and curves changing in x only
fig, axs =plt.subplots(1,2)
colors = g
rainbow_fill_between(axs[0],X,Y1,Y2,colors=colors)
axs[0].plot(X,Y1,'k-',lw=4)
axs[0].plot(X,Y2,'k-',lw=4)

#Plot fill and curves changing in x and y
colors = np.outer(g,g)
rainbow_fill_between(axs[1],X,Y1,Y2,colors=colors)
axs[1].plot(X,Y1,'k-',lw=4)
axs[1].plot(X,Y2,'k-',lw=4)
plt.show()
```

The result is,
[image]

Comment: Nice example, maybe you could add your `rect()` function in order to give a self consistant example. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Ger, didn't realise I forgot this and `rect` is actually not trivial

Answer (score 7):

Your solution is great and flexible ! In particular the 2D case is really nice. Such a feature could be added to `fill_between` maybe if the colors kwargs of the function would accept an array of the same length of x and y ?

Here is a simpler case for the 1D case using the `fill_between` function. It does the same but as it use trapezes instead of rectangle the result is smoother.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm

# Select a color map
cmap = mpl.cm.bwr

# Some Test data
npts = 100
x = np.linspace(-4, 4, npts)
y = norm.pdf(x)
z = np.sin(2 * x)
normalize = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=z.min(), vmax=z.max())

# The plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0.12, 0.12, 0.68, 0.78])
plt.plot(x, y, color="gray")
for i in range(npts - 1):
    plt.fill_between([x[i], x[i+1]], [y[i], y[i+1]], color=cmap(normalize(z[i])))

cbax = fig.add_axes([0.85, 0.12, 0.05, 0.78])
cb = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(cbax, cmap=cmap, norm=normalize, orientation='vertical')
cb.set_label("Sin function", rotation=270, labelpad=15)
plt.show()
```

[image]