# Pyplot: vertical gradient fill under curve?

Tags: python, matplotlib, gradient

I'm wondering if there's a way to fill under a pyplot curve with a vertical gradient, like in this quick mockup:

[image]

I found this hack on StackOverflow, and I don't mind the polygons if I could figure out how to make the color map vertical: [How to fill rainbow color under a curve in Python matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215276/how-to-fill-rainbow-color-under-a-curve-in-python-matplotlib)

Answer (score 13):

There may be a better way, but here goes:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = range(10)
y = range(10)
z = [[z] * 10 for z in range(10)]
num_bars = 100  # more bars = smoother gradient

plt.contourf(x, y, z, num_bars)

background_color = 'w'
plt.fill_between(x, y, y2=max(y), color=background_color)

plt.show()
```

Shows:

[image]

Comment: That's pretty good thinking outside the box, having a gradient background and a white fill over it. It would not have occurred to me any time soon.

Comment: instead of `plt.contourf` I would use `plt.imshow` for the gradient fill. See [my answer to this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42971319/4375377).

Answer (score 7):

There is an alternative solution closer to the sketch in the question. It's given on Henry Barthes' blog http://pradhanphy.blogspot.com/2014/06/filling-between-curves-with-color.html.
This applies an imshow to each of the patches, I've copied the code in case the link changes,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.path import Path
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch

xx=np.arange(0,10,0.01)
yy=xx*np.exp(-xx)

path = Path(np.array([xx,yy]).transpose())
patch = PathPatch(path, facecolor='none')
plt.gca().add_patch(patch)

im = plt.imshow(xx.reshape(yy.size,1),   
                cmap=plt.cm.Reds,
                interpolation="bicubic",
                origin='lower',
                extent=[0,10,-0.0,0.40],
                aspect="auto",
                clip_path=patch, 
                clip_on=True)
plt.show()
```