# cmap parameter in ax.fill_between()

Tags: python, matplotlib

Matplotlib's `ax.fill_between` plotting function has the `cmap` parameter and I was trying to use it to fill the area under the curve with a gradient.
However, setting `cmap` in this function doesn't seem to be doing anything or I'm missing something?

This is what I've tried:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [2, 4, 1, 3, 0.5, 2]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(
    figsize=(10,6),
    facecolor="white"
)

ax.fill_between(
    x=x,
    y1=y,
    cmap="cool"
)
```

and another version of it:

```
ax.fill_between(
    x=x,
    y1=y,
    cmap=plt.get_cmap("cool")
)
```

I would also try to apply `cmap` to `color` or `facecolor` property but it would throw an error.

So all I always end up with is this:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to get color gradients under curve in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29321835/is-it-possible-to-get-color-gradients-under-curve-in-matplotlib)

Comment: Not really. 
I know there are work arounds like the one you've posted where you create image with a gradient and use the shape of the curve to clip it.
My question is: **WHY** is there a `cmap` parameter in `fill_between` function if it does nothing? Or if it works as with any other plotting function - how to properly use it?