# How to colour MatPlotLib graph with gradient colour

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a graph in python I've made with matplotlib with the following code:

```
def to_percent(y, position):
    s = str(250 * y)
    if matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex'] is True:
        return s + r'$\%$'
    else:
        return s + '%'

distance = df['Distance']
perctile = np.percentile(distance, 90) # claculates 90th percentile
bins = np.arange(0,perctile,2.5)  # creates list increasing by 2.5 to 90th percentile 
plt.hist(distance, bins = bins, normed=True)
formatter = FuncFormatter(to_percent)  #changes y axis to percent
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
plt.axis([0, perctile, 0, 0.10])  #Defines the axis' by the 90th percentile and 10%Relative frequency
plt.xlabel('Length of Trip (Km)')
plt.title('Relative Frequency of Trip Distances')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

What I'd like to know is, is it possible to colour the bars with gradient instead of block colour, like in this picture from excel.

[image]

I've not been able to find any information on this.

Comment: Instead of calling `hist` you could use `numpy.histogram` and plot with `bar`.   Then [example from the documentation](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/gradient_bar.html) would apply.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fill matplotlib bars with a gradient?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38830250/how-to-fill-matplotlib-bars-with-a-gradient)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [`gradient_bar.py`](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/gradient_bar.html) example from the `matplotlib` documentation.

The basic idea is that you don't use the [`hist()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist) method from `pyplot`, but build the barchart yourself by using [`imshow()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow)  instead. The first argument to `imshow()` contains the color map which will be displayed inside of the box specified by the `extent` argmument.

Here's a simplified version of the example cited above that should get you on the track. It uses the values from your Excel example, and a color map that uses the [CSS colors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors.asp) 'dodgerblue' and 'royalblue' for a linear gradient.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors as mcolors

values = [22, 15, 14, 10, 7, 5, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7]

# set up xlim and ylim for the plot axes:
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xlim(0, len(values))
ax.set_ylim(0, max(values))

# Define start and end color as RGB values. The names are standard CSS color
# codes.
start_color = mcolors.hex2color(mcolors.cnames["dodgerblue"])
end_color = mcolors.hex2color(mcolors.cnames["royalblue"])

# color map:
img = [[start_color], [end_color]]

for x, y in enumerate(values):
    # draw an 'image' using the color map at the 
    # given coordinates
    ax.imshow(img, extent=(x, x + 1, 0, y))

plt.show()
```