# Bar plot with color gradient on each bar. Error: TypeError: object of type 'ListedColormap' has no len()

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, bar-chart, colormap

I'm willing to generate such a plot:[image]

I have troubles defining the colormap as a color for each bar. How Can I do that?
I have written the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
quiz=[1,2,0,4,8,10]
plt.barh(range(len(quiz)), quiz, align='center', alpha=0.5, color='blue')
```

It works but all the bars are just of one color(blue here). How to use a colormap as a color?

```
color=plt.cm.get_cmap('bwr')
```

gives an

```
Error: TypeError: object of type 'ListedColormap' has no len()
```

Edit: This post gives some hints, but doesn't tell me how to make the color gradient correspond to the x values: [How to fill matplotlib bars with a gradient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38830250/how-to-fill-matplotlib-bars-with-a-gradient)

Comment: In the linked example, you only have to fiddle with this line (I think): `grad = np.atleast_2d(np.linspace(0,1,256)).T`, to scale the `256` according to the length of your bars. E.g. for the longest bar you would use 256 and for the others a smaller number. For instance if the longest bar is 10, a bar of length 8 would use `int(8*256/10)`.

Comment: Finally got the right edit. It was tricky, since ax.imshow does a normalization by default... You need to know that and it's tricky to fix it... Not super intuitive to me. I would leave this question as related but not duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So , inspired by  Thomas Kühn's comment, I got a solution (not sure it's the cleanest one, but it works).

It basically puts an image with the gradient over the initial horizontal barplot.
ax.imshow() normalizes by default the given values. Therefore to make the gradient depend on the x values, we need to remove this forced normalization using the option norm=mpl.colors.NoNorm(vmin=0,vmax=1):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
data=[4,5,6,3,7,5]  
bar = ax.barh(range(len(data)),data)
def gradientbars(bars):
      
      ax = bars[0].axes
      lim = ax.get_xlim()+ax.get_ylim()
      for bar in bars:
          
          bar.set_zorder(1)
          bar.set_facecolor("none")
          x,y = bar.get_xy()
          w, h = bar.get_width(), bar.get_height()
          grad = np.atleast_2d(np.linspace(0,1*w/max(data),256))
          ax.imshow(grad, extent=[x,x+w,y,y+h], aspect="auto", zorder=0, norm=mpl.colors.NoNorm(vmin=0,vmax=1))
      ax.axis(lim)  
  
gradientbars(bar)
```

Result:
[image]

You can also change the colormap using the option `cmap` in `ax.imshow()`, for example:
`cmap = plt.get_cmap('coolwarm')`

Comment: But what is the use of this solution if the color gradient of the bars does not correspond to the x-value?

Comment: Yes, you're right, I fixed that now!