# Replicating Microsoft Excel's Data Bar Gradient Conditional Formatting Using Python / Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, formatting, data-visualization

Is there a Python package or library which allows data to be visualised in a similar way to the data bar (gradient fill) conditional formatting of Microsoft Excel:

[image: gradient fill]

If not gradient fill, the perhaps solid fill like this:

[image: solid fill]

I'm wondering whether Pandas or another Python library has this functionality?

Comment: The matplotlib docs have a tutorial on that [topic](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/gradient_bar.html).

Comment: There are also posts such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38830250/how-to-fill-matplotlib-bars-with-a-gradient)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some sample data would have been handy.

**Generate data :**

```
data ={'MM-DD':['Jan-01-2019', 'Feb-02-2019', 'Mar-03-2019', 'Apr-04-2019', 'May-05-2019', 'Jun-06-2019','Jul-07-2019', 'Aug-08-2019', 'Sep-09-2019', 'Oct-10-2019', 'Nov-11-2019', 'Dec-12-2019'], 'clients':[12, 34, 67, 2, 12, 17,2, 5, 43, 32, 2, 7]}
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df



 df.set_index(df['MM-DD'], inplace=True)
 df['Dates']=df.index.strftime('%b-%d')
```

**Plot in [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.barh.html) library**

```
import matplotlib .pyplot as plt
plt.barh( df['Dates'],df['clients'])
plt.ylabel('Dates')
plt.title('2018')
plt.show
```

[image]

**Can also use** [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html) **library**

```
import seaborn as sns
ax = sns.barplot(x=df['clients'], y=df['Dates'])
plt.title("2018")
```

[image]