# Adjust bar plot gradient with x axis limit

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, limit, gradient

I have a bar plot with gradient colours on the bar, however when I change the x-axis limits, the gradient is still applied to the original x values (i.e. changing the x-axis limits from 0-10 to 5-10, the gradient is still applied to 0-10 and the new plot only shows half of the gradient):

[image]
[image]

I used [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48814728/19887504) which applies a gradient colour to bars in matplotlib:

```
def gradientbars(bars):
    '''Function to apply gradient colour over bars'''
    grad = np.atleast_2d(np.linspace(0,1,256))
    ax = bars[0].axes
    lim = ax.get_xlim()+ax.get_ylim()
    for bar in bars:
        bar.set_zorder(1)
        bar.set_facecolor("none")
        x,y = bar.get_xy()
        w, h = bar.get_width(), bar.get_height()
        ax.imshow(grad, extent=[x,x+w,y,y+h], aspect="auto", zorder=0, cmap = "Blues")
    ax.axis(lim)
```

And this function to plot the bar plot:

```
def bar_plot(position, x_axis, title):

    # Opening figure & axis
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    # Creating scatter plot
    bar = ax.barh(position['Player'], position[x_axis])
    # Applying gradient function
    gradientbars(bar)
    # Setting x-axis limits
    plt.xlim([5, 10])
```

Is it possible to alter the code so that the gradient is applied to the new plot with x-axis limits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ax.imshow()` is where the color gradient is set. As you will start your plot at x=5, you will need to set the `extent` also to start at that position. More information on extent is available [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/imshow_extent.html). Note that is hard coded to 5, but you can send a variable with the number you want. A fully running example is given below to showcase the same.

```
def gradientbars(bars):
    '''Function to apply gradient colour over bars'''
    grad = np.atleast_2d(np.linspace(0,1,256))
    ax = bars[0].axes
    lim = ax.get_xlim()+ax.get_ylim()
    for bar in bars:
        bar.set_zorder(1)
        bar.set_facecolor("none")
        x,y = bar.get_xy()
        w, h = bar.get_width(), bar.get_height()
        ##Changed the start of x from x to x+5 so the gradient starts there
        ax.imshow(grad, extent=[x+5,x+w,y,y+h], aspect="auto", zorder=0, cmap = "Blues")
    ax.axis(lim)
    
def bar_plot(position, x_axis, title):

    # Opening figure & axis
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    # Creating scatter plot
    bar = ax.barh(position['Player'], position[x_axis])
    # Setting x-axis limits
    plt.xlim([5, 10])
    # Applying gradient function
    gradientbars(bar)
    
df=pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.randint(6, 10, size=(10)), 'Player' : np.arange(1,11)}) ## Random data BETWEEN 5-11
bar_plot(df, 'x','Ploty plot')
```

**Plot**

[image]