# Can I create a horizontal gradient with `fill_between`?

Tags: matplotlib

I want to use `fill_between` in order to highlight stress levels.

My current solution to visualize this is:

```
for i in range(len(u)-1):    
    x = u[i]
    x1 = i
    x2 = i+1    
    off = idxvec[0] + offset

    stress = ((u[i] - l[i])/40)**2.

    ranges.append(stress)
    ax1.fill_between([off+i, off+i+1], [u[i], u[i+1]], [l[i], l[i+1]], alpha=stress, facecolor='red')
```

which means I set the `alpha` value for each slice individually as I scan over my data.

However, this is slow and ugly. Is there a way to do this faster/nicer?

I imagine something like a `list` of alpha values that I provide `fill_between` and the result is a horizontal gradient:

```
ax1.fill_between(x, y1, y2, alpha=[0.2, 0.3, ..., 0.4, 0.3])
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pyplot: vertical gradient fill under curve?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22081361/pyplot-vertical-gradient-fill-under-curve)

Comment: No, it's not possible. You need to use some workaround like the one you already have or using an image that is clipped.