# Plotting Error Bars As Gradients

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, probability

I have a series of observations for risk and performance (x, y co-ordinates). These are based on a series of bootstrap samples. I also have the 5th and 95th percentiles of the bootstrap samples - these represent the 90% probability window around the observations.

As it stands I am plotting this data as a scatter, then using error bars to show the probability window around the observation. Note the error bars are not symmetrical on either axis.

I'd like to instead plot these as an ellipse around the center point, ideally with a gradient going from an alpha of 1 at the center to ~0.2 at the edge.

Could anyone give me a nudge in the correct direction for this? Equally if anyone has a more elegant way to demonstrate a probability window around points on a scatter I'm happy to try it.

Comment: StackOverflow expects a [MVCE] before you get advice. Work up a first try with sized patches but not a gradient, for instance.

Comment: I guess you can directly use the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46016782/how-to-shade-under-curve-in-matplotlib-but-with-variable-color-alpha).