# Distplot with varying color from left to right

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I came across this image today and I am curious if it is possible to reproduce it using matplotlib or seaborn. The waterfall part can be done with **sns.FacetGrid**, but I do not know how to force area under the curve to change color from left to right. Any ideas? 
[image]

Comment: You might want to google for "gradient fill under curve matplotlib".

Comment: Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22081361/pyplot-vertical-gradient-fill-under-curve), although it's vertical gradient, but I think you can figure out how to make it horizontal.

Comment: @QuangHoang, that example works ok for filling but what if you're hoping to pass the gradient to a histogram?