# plotting 2d fit probability distribution as color gradient in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, gradient

I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to make plots similar to the plots of the posterior probability distribution (in red) similar to those found on [page 17 here](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~dduvenaud/thesis.pdf).

It is clear that these are many lines with low alpha values overlaid.  This gives the effect of dark red in the middle with the shading gradually lightening as you move outwards.  I have found it difficult choosing combination of the right alpha and number of lines to overlay to achieve that effect.

What I wish I could do was to use something similar to `fill_between` but instead of a shaded area, have the shading smoothly fade out as you get to the edges.  Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you have the functional form of the posterior?  If so, you can just you can create a 2-d grid (e.g., with `np.meshgrid()`) and make the value of every cell equal to the posterior for that cell.

Comment: I'm afraid I may end up having to do it that way.  Looking closer at the linked picture, it looks like they repeatedly called `fill_between` to create that effect.

Comment: Maybe, but a simpler way to achieve the same look would be with `matplotlib.pyplot.contourf()`.

Comment: The answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29656697/588071) might be of some use