# Fill between subplots with matplotlib cmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, gradient

I have 2 line plots on the same figure, plotted from pandas dataframes.

I want to fill between them with a gradient/colour map of sorts.

I understand I can do this with a cmap, only it will not work for me (see code below).

General example I found are filling between x axis and line, i do not want that and also i am interested in simplest solution possible for this as i am a begginer at this and complicated, though maybe better code will just make it more confusing honestly.

Code for which fill is plain blue:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

ax = plt.gca()

df0.plot(kind='line', x='something', y='other', color='orange', ax=ax, legend=False, figsize=(20,10))
df1.plot(kind='line', x='something', y='other2', color='c', ax=ax, legend=False, figsize=(20,10))

ax.fill_between(x=df0['daysInAYear'], y1=df0['other'], y2 = df1['other2'], alpha=0.2, cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap("winter"))
plt.show()
```

EDIT/UPDATE: DATA EXAMPLE
other is ALWAYS >= other2

```
other  other2  something (same for both)
15.6    -16.0      1
13.9    -26.7      2
13.3    -26.7      3
10.6    -26.1      4
12.8    -15.0      5
```

Final graph example:
[image: example]

I would like the fill to go from orange on top to blue at the bottom

Comment: Can you add some simple data for df0 and df1?

Comment: added in the original post, also an image.

Comment: @ryuuzako Have you had a chance to try the method in my answer?

Comment: @WilliamMiller hey, i didn't get around it but i promise once i do that i will update here!

Answer (score 3):

#### Edit

In response to the edited question, here is an alternative approach which does the gradient vertically but doesn't use `imshow`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from  matplotlib import colors, patches
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n = 100
nc = 100

x = np.linspace(0, np.pi*5, n)
y1 = [-50.0]
y2 = [50.0]
for ii in range(1, n):
    y1.append(y1[ii-1] + (np.random.random()-0.3)*3)
    y2.append(y2[ii-1] + (np.random.random()-0.5)*3)
y1 = np.array(y1)
y2 = np.array(y2)
z = np.linspace(0, 10, nc)
normalize = colors.Normalize(vmin=z.min(), vmax=z.max())
cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('winter')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
for ii in range(len(df['x'].values)-1):
    y = np.linspace(y1[ii], y2[ii], nc)
    yn = np.linspace(y1[ii+1], y2[ii+1], nc)
    for kk in range(nc - 1):
        p = patches.Polygon([[x[ii], y[kk]], 
                             [x[ii+1], yn[kk]], 
                             [x[ii+1], yn[kk+1]], 
                             [x[ii], y[kk+1]]], color=cmap(normalize(z[kk])))
        ax.add_patch(p)

plt.plot(x, y1, 'k-', lw=1)
plt.plot(x, y2, 'k-', lw=1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

The idea here being similar to that in my original answer, except the trapezoids are divided into `nc` pieces and each piece is colored separately. This has the advantage of scaling correctly for varying `y1[ii]`, `y2[ii]` distances, as shown in this comparison,

[image]

It does, however, have the disadvantages of being much, *much* slower than `imshow` or the horizontal gradient method and of being unable to handle 'crossing' correctly.

The code to generate the second image in the above comparison:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import patches
from matplotlib.path import Path

x = np.linspace(0, 10, n)
y1 = [-50.0]
y2 = [50.0]
for ii in range(1, n):
    y1.append(y1[ii-1] + (np.random.random()-0.2)*3)
    y2.append(y2[ii-1] + (np.random.random()-0.5)*3)
y1 = np.array(y1)
y2 = np.array(y2)

verts = np.vstack([np.stack([x, y1], 1), np.stack([np.flip(x), np.flip(y2)], 1)])
path = Path(verts)

patch = patches.PathPatch(path, facecolor='k', lw=2, alpha=0.0)
plt.gca().add_patch(patch)

plt.imshow(np.arange(10).reshape(10,-1), cmap=plt.cm.winter, interpolation="bicubic",
             origin='upper', extent=[0,10,-60,60], aspect='auto', clip_path=patch, 
             clip_on=True)
plt.show()
```

---

#### Original

This is a bit of a hack, partly based on the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564273/matplotlib-continuous-colormap-fill-between-two-lines/29656697). It does seem to work fairly well but works best with higher density along the `x` axis. The idea is to call `fill_between` separately for each trapezoid corresponding to `x` pairs, `[x[ii], x[ii+1]]`. Here is a complete example using some generated data

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from  matplotlib import colors
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n = 1000

X = np.linspace(0, np.pi*5, n)
Y1 = np.sin(X)
Y2 = np.cos(X)
Z = np.linspace(0, 10, n)
normalize = colors.Normalize(vmin=Z.min(), vmax=Z.max())
cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('winter')

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': X, 'y1': Y1, 'y2': Y2, 'z': Z})
x = df['x'].values
y1 = df['y1'].values
y2 = df['y2'].values
z = df['z'].values

for ii in range(len(df['x'].values)-1):
    plt.fill_between([x[ii], x[ii+1]], [y1[ii], y1[ii+1]], 
                     [y2[ii], y2[ii+1]], color=cmap(normalize(z[ii])))

plt.plot(x, y1, 'k-', x, y2, 'k-')
plt.show()
```

[image]

This can be generalized to a 2 dimensional color grid but would require non-trivial modification

Comment: Since imshow is much faster than plotting hundreds of patches it's not really clear why one should try to avoid using it.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Perhaps I was unclear. I’m not saying `imshow` ought to be avoided, I’m simply saying this is a way to do it which does not use `imshow`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest The reason to use this method over `imshow`, as I see it, is outlined by [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWpn3.png) and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aJMF.png) where clipping the `imshow` does not produce the correct gradient with variable `y1` and `y2` distances or when `y1` and/or `y2` have with `x`. How would you use `imshow` to produce the correct gradient in these cases?

Comment: The question remains a bit unclear on how exactly the gradient is supposed to look (i.e. if it is a gradient *per x data point*, or a global gradient. The latter would make much more sense though(?)). In any case, you can always create an image that looks like the desired outcome, so not sure what exactly is the problem.

Comment: Could you please provide the code based on imshow, for horizontal gradient method where the colours defined with y value only? I have exactly the same question, but I find the answer unsatisfactory. Is this the only way to do the colour gradient inside fill_between?

Comment: I meant for the _vertical_ gradient, like in the right panel of the above comparison.

Comment: @Vladimir I have added the code for the `plt.imshow` approach

Comment: Thanks! That is also much more elegant and faster approach. I understand the first image has different prior, but I can not imagine any reasonable use for such varying vertical gradient in practice, except that it is prettier.